# Tkinter destroy and file reading

Tags: python, file, tkinter, destroy

I've been assigned to do a project for my python class in college, we're supposed to do a program for a store, but I've been having some issues with tkinter. I've done a main menu, from there the user can register as a buyer, and con also buy. I finished the registration window, but I need the button not only to run another function I've already created that saves the data that the user inputs in a list, but to also to destroy the window. is there a way to make the button run 2 commands?
Here's an example of what I have:

```
def get_data(l):
    l.append(box1.get())
    l.append(box2.get())
    l.append(box3.get())
    l.append(box4.get())
def register():
    global box1
    global box2
    global box3
    global box4
    #code defining window and each label and each input box
    botonA= Button(registerwindow, text = "accept",command=lambda: get_data(mylist), width=5)
    botonA.grid(row=0,column=2)
```

How can I assign the button to not just run the get_data function, but also to close the window?

My second question is how to open or import a file in tkinter, I've searched and all I get is how to make the user open a file, In our program we have the files with the required information already edited, we only need to get and use the  data inside those files (the items in the store, how much there is in stock,price, etc), is there a way to import the file without the user having to select it?

Thanks. 
(Sorry if I didn't post any code, most of my variables and stuff is in spanish so I'm trying to avoid translating as much as I can, but If you guys need samples, I would be happy to deliver)

Comment: Your question is way too broad. You need to ask a specific question, and show what you've done to attempt to solve that problem.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to translate some sample code for reference

Answer (score 0):

Just pass a reference to the window you'd like to `destroy()` as an argument to the function:

```
def mywindow():
    topwindow = Toplevel()
    button = Button(topwindow, text='ok', command=lambda: okbutton(topwindow, mylist))

def okbutton(widget, l):
    l.append('hello world')
    widget.destroy()
```

As far as opening a file without asking the user to select it, you can simply hard-code a value in there instead of using something like `input()`:

```
# filename = input('filename? ')
filename = 'input_data.txt'
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    pass # process file
```